Are there any numbers that seem to be irrational but are not?
I am looking for an example of a number that was conjectured to be irrational. This number should have been calculated to many decimal places, showing no discernible pattern, so it truly seemed irrational at first. However, it was later proven to be rational. Even after knowing it is rational, finding its exact fractional representation should be very challenging.
I’d also like the process of calculating the number to be easy to describe—similar to how one might describe calculating $\pi$. For instance, if someone told me that a number is "$\sqrt{6\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{k^2}}$" I would understand that this converges, and I could compute it to 100 decimal places. But I might still guess the result is irrational however I would not be able to prove this.
Is there a similar number but someone has proved that eventually it will be rational?
Does such a number exist? Is my question clear, or should I rephrase it?

Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967/have-any-long-suspected-irrational-numbers-turned-out-to-be-rational

@user1386629 SE sites don't regard each other's content as duplicates, but thanks for that link because it's a really interesting find.
